# Formatting the width of y-axis labels

Tags: excel, vba, charts, axis-labels

I am working on a VBA Excel script that uses a pivot table to create a bunch of charts and copy them into a Word document, creating a report.
The charts come in pairs and, after pasting them, there's a slight "distance" between the y-axes.
I wish to have them make a single line if they were extended.

I'm using the `TickLables.Offset` property. It's set to the same value in both charts, yet that doesn't do the trick.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit:

A screenshot of the issue: 
[image: Screenshot of issue]

Code:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.TickLabels.AutoScaleFont = True
With Selection.TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Normal"
    .Size = 10
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Background = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.TickLabels
    .Offset = 500
End With
```

Comment: show the appropriate code an you could also attach a screen shot presenting the problem...

Comment: There you have it, I was interrupted while editting this post and forgot...

Comment: I completly forgot about your question... :( is it still valid for you? What I see based on your picture- the reason is the length of the y-axis values. Offsetting both with the same values do nothing. You should rather set different Offset values to both charts to get appropriate results. Some test could be required...

Comment: Don't sweat, I worked around it by setting the `Orientation` property of the `TickLabels` to `xlUpward`.

That still doesn't resolve my issue, so I'm keeping this topic open.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Offset` is an inter percentage, as in `.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Offset` it is hard to pin down.  To align things, in my case within a single chart, I get perfect results with:

```
.Legend.Left = .PlotArea.Left + .PlotArea.Width - .PlotArea.InsideWidth

.Legend.Width = .PlotArea.InsideWidth
```

In other words when you have TickLables only on the left (or right), the width of the Ticklables is the difference between the inside and outside Widths.